# Sci-kit Learn Mutual Information Classification- Dataframe and function issues

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn

I've currently got the below set of smoothed data:

```
print(df_smooth.dropna())`
```

```
       mean       std      skew  kurtosis  peak2peak       rms  crestFactor  \
4   0.247555  2.100961  0.001668  3.024679  20.628402  2.115862     5.066747   
5   0.237015  2.062690 -0.000792  3.029156  20.314159  2.076466     5.043114   
6   0.230783  2.044657 -0.001680  3.028746  20.219575  2.057846     5.030472   
7   0.235838  1.986232 -0.001031  3.025417  19.497090  2.000425     4.960363   
8   0.235062  1.984086 -0.001014  3.031342  19.817176  1.998209     4.989612   
9   0.238660  1.968814 -0.001608  3.023882  19.340179  1.983427     4.998115   
10  0.223305  1.975597 -0.000197  3.045224  19.701747  1.988305     5.135947   
11  0.219480  2.007902 -0.002460  3.060428  20.252087  2.020074     5.117502   
12  0.214518  2.071287 -0.002944  3.092217  21.489908  2.082439     5.302407   
13  0.244281  2.122538 -0.003717  3.094335  21.792449  2.137164     5.271366   
14  0.235806  2.161333 -0.003364  3.123866  23.128965  2.174895     5.472129   
15  0.233630  2.175946 -0.002682  3.152740  24.045300  2.189226     5.610038   
16  0.236764  2.188906 -0.000032  3.203623  24.745386  2.202420     5.772337   
17  0.262289  2.205111  0.000350  3.192511  24.708587  2.221785     5.681394   
18  0.229795  2.139946  0.001239  3.183109  23.745617  2.152940     5.564731   
19  0.243538  2.150018  0.001071  3.170558  23.385026  2.164355     5.427326   
20  0.266458  2.097468 -0.000830  3.144338  22.084817  2.115172     5.236667   
21  0.280729  2.106302 -0.000618  3.101014  21.434129  2.125517     5.147621   
22  0.252042  2.078190  0.000259  3.100911  20.991519  2.093988     5.231684   
23  0.252297  2.097652  0.000383  3.126250  21.790854  2.113380     5.378267   
24  0.250502  2.078781  0.000042  3.129014  21.559732  2.094428     5.340024   
25  0.220506  2.070573  0.001974  3.110477  21.473643  2.082461     5.364519   
26  0.204412  2.049979 -0.000306  3.227532  22.975315  2.060236     5.706146   
27  0.215429  2.103150 -0.001421  3.275257  23.719901  2.114265     5.660891   
28  0.216689  2.137870 -0.001783  3.298750  24.040561  2.148948     5.614089   
29  0.208962  2.160487  0.000547  3.349068  24.546959  2.170628     5.732873   
30  0.227231  2.267705  0.000101  3.413948  25.958169  2.279131     5.745555   
31  0.221097  2.258519  0.001567  3.379193  25.424651  2.269446     5.662354   
32  0.204962  2.224569  0.000951  3.458483  25.984242  2.234101     5.862379   
33  0.224707  2.283631  0.000046  3.516125  27.410217  2.294934     6.024091   
34  0.248792  2.354713 -0.001143  3.630634  29.159253  2.368248     6.197140   
35  0.229501  2.339020 -0.000673  3.743356  30.695670  2.350898     6.613011   
36  0.255474  2.454993 -0.001164  3.780962  32.480614  2.468843     6.627903   
37  0.257979  2.530495  0.000630  3.962767  33.656646  2.544310     6.661273   
38  0.232977  2.498537  0.001111  3.931879  32.754947  2.510044     6.557506   
39  0.237025  2.392735 -0.000920  3.919665  31.277647  2.405969     6.494115   
40  0.243630  2.368295 -0.001569  3.812383  29.306347  2.382131     6.077379   
41  0.221252  2.305374 -0.000861  4.032235  29.548822  2.317355     6.292428   
42  0.215262  2.254417 -0.002057  3.977328  28.970507  2.266098     6.353168   
43  0.208581  2.240020 -0.001403  4.154288  30.121039  2.251270     6.630079   
44  0.170230  2.302794 -0.001867  4.307822  31.556097  2.309174     6.838202   
45  0.168889  2.353960 -0.001309  4.433633  32.825109  2.360053     6.977719   
46  0.163156  2.337222 -0.001097  4.238485  31.344888  2.342934     6.658564   
47  0.165685  2.369817 -0.002246  4.151915  31.154929  2.375626     6.438286   
48  0.190677  2.552397 -0.003645  4.311166  33.473407  2.559565     6.428513   
49  0.210200  2.667889  0.004168  4.495159  35.625185  2.676223     6.500683
```

I want to use the sckikit learn Mutual Information Classification to test for Monotonicity in this dataset, but am having trouble with the syntax (more specifically around the X-value) and the splitting of the full dataset into test and train sets.

I only want 40% of the dataset to be used at the "test data".
Currently this is the command I have:

```
X_train,X_test,y_train,y_test=train_test_split(df_smooth.dropna(),
    test_size=0.4,
    random_state=0)
print(X_train)
```

This is the error I get:

```
ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 4, got 2)
from sklearn.feature_selection import mutual_info_classif
mutual_info = mutual_info_classif(X_train, y_train)
```

The output I want is something like this:
[Monotonicity bar chart- descending](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9DBRK.png)

Where the MIC array is ranked from highest to low.
Using the following command:

```
from sklearn.feature_selection import mutual_info_classif
mutual_info = mutual_info_classif(X_train, y_train)
mutual_info
```

I tried extracting the ordered numbers 1-49 from the dataframe (which is what I believe is used as the "x" syntax input into the MCI function), but they don't seem to be part of the dataframe when called with iloc[:,0] (which displays the values in the "mean" column). I don't know how this takes into account the dropped "n/a" line values.

Comment: Hi there, welcome to StackOverflow  Either I'm completely misunderstanding what this question is asking, or this might be clarified with supporting information. It *looks like* you're trying to estimate the degree of monotonicity between sequences, but the function you're using is a feature selection technique that tries to estimate independence between a feature and the target variable.

Comment: My two cents: you *probably* don't want to use mutual information for this, and you *probably* shouldn't use scikit-learn feature selection like this.

Answer (score 0):

If you're testing for something like "the degree of monotonicity between two variables," you're probably looking for [Spearman's rank correlation coefficient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spearman%27s_rank_correlation_coefficient), which is implemented in [`scipy.stats.spearmanr`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.spearmanr.html):

**MRE**:

```py
from io import StringIO
import pandas as pd
from scipy import stats

data = StringIO("""mean,std,skew,kurtosis,peak2peak,rms,crestFactor
0.247555,2.100961,0.001668,3.024679,20.628402,2.115862,5.066747
0.237015,2.062690,-0.000792,3.029156,20.314159,2.076466,5.043114
0.230783,2.044657,-0.001680,3.028746,20.219575,2.057846,5.030472
0.235838,1.986232,-0.001031,3.025417,19.497090,2.000425,4.960363
0.235062,1.984086,-0.001014,3.031342,19.817176,1.998209,4.989612
""")

df = pd.read_csv(data)

for var in df.columns:
    print(f"{var} {stats.spearmanr(df[var], range(len(df))).correlation:.2f}")
```

Comparing the first five values of each column to the strictly monotonic sequence `range()` yields the following table, suggesting the first few samples are antimonotone:

```
mean         -0.70
std          -1.00
skew         -0.60
kurtosis      0.60
peak2peak    -0.90
rms          -1.00
crestFactor  -0.90
```